# What should return trigger BEFORE DELETE

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am trying to make simple trigger function (Postgresql) but I am getting same error **'function did not return any row'** in all these cases (just simple examples):

New:

```
UPDATE somewhere SET something = something - 1;
RETURN NEW;
```

Old:

```
UPDATE somewhere SET something = something - 1;
RETURN OLD;
```

What should I return when I call this function "before delete"? ("after insert/update" works well)

Tyvm for tips!

Full code as requested:
Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pictogram_frequency_on_delete()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

new_frequency RECORD;
target_unit RECORD;
current_row RECORD;
units_with_same_type RECORD;
what RECORD; 

BEGIN
SET search_path TO 'myScheme';

CASE TG_OP
WHEN 'DELETED' THEN what := OLD;
ELSE what:= OLD;
END CASE;

SELECT unit_type_uid INTO STRICT target_unit 
FROM unit 
WHERE unit_uid = what.unit_uid;

SELECT count(*) AS exists INTO STRICT current_row 
FROM unit_type_pictogram utp 
WHERE utp.pictogram_uid = what.pictogram_uid 
AND utp.unit_type_uid = target_unit.unit_type_uid;

IF (current_row.exists = 0) THEN
    RETURN what; /* return new/old doesnt work too */
END IF;

UPDATE unit_type_pictogram utp 
SET frequency = frequency - 1
WHERE utp.pictogram_uid = what.pictogram_uid 
AND utp.unit_type_uid = target_unit.unit_type_uid;

RETURN what; /* return new/old doesnt work too */

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_delete_frequency
BEFORE DELETE
ON unit_pictogram
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE pictogram_frequency_on_delete();
```

Comment: please post complete code

Comment: @JGH posted full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/trigger-definition.html):

> Trigger functions invoked by per-statement triggers should always
>   return NULL. Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return
>   a table row (a value of type HeapTuple) to the calling executor, if
>   they choose. A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the
>   following choices:
>
> - It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
>     invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
>     particular table row).
> - For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers only, the returned row becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being
>     updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being
>     inserted or updated.
>
> A row-level BEFORE trigger that does not intend to cause either of
>   these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row
>   that was passed in (that is, the NEW row for INSERT and UPDATE
>   triggers, the OLD row for DELETE triggers).

---

### EDIT

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pictogram_frequency_on_delete()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  UPDATE unit_type_pictogram AS utp
    SET frequency = frequency - 1
    FROM unit
    WHERE utp.pictogram_uid = OLD.pictogram_uid
      AND unit_uid = OLD.unit_uid
      AND utp.unit_type_uid = unit.unit_type_uid;
  RETURN OLD;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Yea, it says "OLD row for DELETE triggers" but it returns error for me

Comment: Show us the **whole** function.

Comment: That is not a function, just a PL/PgSQL block... Also show us the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: It is there too now, any idea what if wrong? All my triggers which are after delete or update works fine.

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Comment: The debugger is a part of my web application based on Nette.

Comment: Whole error (translated)
`Request did not return any row
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL fuunction pictogram_frequency_on_delete() row 17 on SQL query
SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "myScheme"."unit_pictogram" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "unit_uid""`

Comment: If my function is absolutly empty, and returns only OLD, it works - as soon as I add any "SELECT" to my function, it returns error

Comment: Found the error already, debugger just gave me wrong Exceptions :( tyvm for your time, UPed your answer

Comment: At first glance `exists` is a reserved word.... Also `CASE` is not a statement, but a "expression"....

Comment: I don't know why, but my pgAdmin doesn't "marks" word exists as reserved word and it works. Case is experssion, but my dubugger told me to add "Else" statement :/

Comment: Oh, yeah: the semicolon inside the `CASE` expression is terminating it...

Answer (score 3):

You should `RETURN OLD;`.

Your function must be defined as `RETURNS trigger`.

Comment: I am using "RETURN OLD" but  debugger returns error "'function did not return any row". How do you mean "Must be defined as returns trigger"?